# The story has gone into the future, had gone a few years ahead; go into past

Tags: word-usage

A story is taking place in the present but then it is like "5 years later" or "5 years ago", what will be a natural way to express that:

5 years ahead:

> The story has gone a few years ahead.  (Or being specific: 5 yrs ahead)
>
> The story has gone into the future. (When not being specific)
>   [I guess this one doesn't sound natural....]

A few years ago or 5 yrs ago:

> The story has gone a few years behind.
>
> The story has gone into the past.

I don't think either of my sentences sound natural... So how will you express it?

Comment: It's easier to convey these changes with a different narrative, like *...we see that five years from now, our protagonist will find herself (in some situation)* or *...five years ago, our protagonist found herself (in some situation).*

Comment: *Five years (later / from now) . . .* and *five years (ago / earlier) . . .*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common verb for this is *skip*

> And so Jim and Susan got married and moved into a nice little cottage with a white picket fence.  Let's **skip forward** five years.  The house is, perhaps, not as white as it once was, mostly from the influence of their two boisterous sons. who are passing through the "mud and magic marker" phase of their artistic development.

You can also "skip *ahead*", "skip *back*", and "skip *over*" some amount of time, as well as various others.

> At this point, the story **skips back** seven years, to when Jim and Susan first met.

(Edit) "Skip" is just one of many other expressions for this. "Roll forward/back", "turn (the clock) forward/back", "jump forward/back", "spin forward/back" ... it's a long list.  A clever writer may use a different verb for moving the clock forward vs. moving the clock back.

*Go*, as in "*go* back" or "*go* forward", isn't really *wrong* as such.  It just sounds awkward to me.  Since we're talking about a *figurative* movement, it's clumsy not to use a more evocative verb.

Comment: But what if I am telling this to someone else?

Comment: And what about the past?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish  You can use "skip" in narration to someone else.  There's not much difference between narrating a story and narrating to another person in conversation.  See my edit for using "skip" with past events.

Comment: And what about "goes back"? "The story has gone back 7 years".

Comment: What will sound more natural :"skip back" or "go back"?

Comment: And will "skip over" mean "skip ahead"?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish  I prefer "skips back".  "Goes back" sounds awkward, although some writers probably use it.  Keep in mind there are many other expressions as well.  "Skip" is just one of many.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish  "Skip over" means just that.  You can go either direction, although going backward would usually require some additional explanation.

Comment: You could also say *The story [**shifts** to the future / past](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22story+shifts+to+the+future%22)*. I'm not saying ***skips*** necessarily implies *skip **forward** [to the future]*, but if that aspect bothers you ***shift*** is a reasonable alternative that can easily go backwards or forwards (or indeed, to a different spatial location, different primary subject, or whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes, please see my edits.  There are many possible verbs.